# selecting a property from FirstOrDefault in case FirstOrDefault returns null

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to make following statement:

```
var block = blocksById.FirstOrDefault(X => X.Value == tracResult.ID).Key
```

My question is how to deal with it more correctly in case I have FirstOrDefault null value.
I just not feel that `if` statments the only solution that can be here...

Comment: When you are using `FirstOrDefault`, you are expecting that the returned value can be null. So, before you do a `.key` you should check returned value for `null`. If a null value in this case is unexpected you should use `First()` and handle null reference exception

Comment: meaning of FirstOrDefault is that you get no result then null value will be outed.. if or conditional operator is the only way to do that..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the introduction of the [null conditional operators (?)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators), it's as simple as:

```
var block = blocksById.FirstOrDefault(X => X.Value == tracResult.ID)?.Key;
```

Keep in mind that in this scenario, even if `Value` is an `int`, `block` will be of type `Nullable<int>`, and hence, can be `null`.

However if what you want to assign a default value if `null` is returned you can make use of [null coalescing operator (??)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) is this way:

```
var block = blocksById.FirstOrDefault(X => X.Value == tracResult.ID)?.Key ?? 6;
```

Nevertheless, for more complex `Select` statements, the following is still valid...

---

#### Some time ago...

Split it in `Where` and `Select`:

```
var block = blocksById.Where(x => x.Value == tracResult.ID)
                      .Select(x => x.Key)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

That way you won't get a NullRefferenceException if the FirstOrDefault returns `null`.

Alternative you can give it a default value like this:

```
var block = blocksById.Where(x => x.Value == tracResult.ID)
                      .Select(x => x.Key)
                      .FirstOrDefault() ?? somedefaultvalue;
```

Or as @Silvermind stated for non nullable to nullable types (`int`'s):

```
var block = blocksById.Where(x => x.Value == tracResult.ID)
                      .Select(x => (int?) x.Key)
                      .FirstOrDefault() ?? somedefaultvalue;
```

---

Update: some people seems to have doubts about this being a valid use case and argue that the check for null has to be done later on in the program.

While in a lot of circumstances this is the case, is doesn't always have to be true, or if it is, it might be more convenient this way.

Some examples:

```
//one liner, null check delegated (not my favorite): 
return SomeCalculatedValue(collection.Where(condition).Select(selection).FirstOrDefault());

//or a mapping (shown with default value):
var result = collection.Where(condition)
                       .Select(c => 
                           { 
                                Foo = c.Foo,
                                Bar = c.Bar
                           }).FirstOrDefault()) ?? new { Foo = "New", Bar = "Empty"};
```

Comment: if my Key is int it's impossible to use ?? operator.

Comment: @NightWalker: True, then FirstOrDefault will revert to `default(int)` which is `0`. You can skip the `??` operator part then.

Comment: @NightWalker You could cast it to a nullable int (`int?`) in the select for the result of `FirstOrDefault()` will be null then.