# How to deal with nulls in Linq to SQL with Regex.Replace on Property

Tags: c#, regex, linq, linq-to-sql

The following portion of code is from a larger linq query, but it is the one I need help with:

```
KnowledgeTypeText = Regex.Replace((from categoryVersion in _Context.ArticleCategoryVersions
                                   join category in _Context.Categories
                                   on categoryVersion.CategoryID equals category.CategoryID
                                   where category.ParentID.HasValue == true
                                   && category.ParentID.Value == rootKnowledgeTypeID
                                   && categoryVersion.Version == articleLatestVersions.Version
                                   && categoryVersion.ArticleID == articleLatestVersions.ArticleID
                                   select category).First().Name, @"(\d+[\\.]?\s*)", ""),
```

The short version: This part of the query will fetch a category for an article, but it doesn't necessary have to have a value. If it does have a value I need to strip out the numbering at the beginning of the text.

I'm getting exceptions when the category is null because it's obviously trying to do the Replace action on the property Name.

How do I add in code to deal with Nulls? It would be safe to return an empty string, but I'm not sure how to test for it and return an empty string.

Comment: Do you really need to inline it? Why not just extract select, do `FirstOrDefault` on it and then replace if the value is not null?

Comment: Is `category` null? or is it's `Name` property `null`? Or is there no item in the sequence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selecting a property from FirstOrDefault in case FirstOrDefault returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947464/selecting-a-property-from-firstordefault-in-case-firstordefault-returns-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you fail on `First()` because `Sequence contains no elements` then replace with `.FirstOrDefault()`.
- If you get a value but it is `null` and then it fails on a null reference when accessing `Name` then use `.FirstOrDefault()?.Name`
- If it is the `Name` property that is `null` then use the `??`:

  ```
  (/* query */).FirstOrDefault()?.Name ?? string.Empty
  ```

Read more on:

- [?. Null-Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)
- [?? Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator)

---

In addition it is less readable putting it all inline like this (even more as it seems to be in an object initializer). First have the query and then do the replace:

```
var result = (from categoryVersion in _Context.ArticleCategoryVersions
              join category in _Context.Categories
              on categoryVersion.CategoryID equals category.CategoryID
              where category.ParentID.HasValue &&
              category.ParentID.Value == rootKnowledgeTypeID &&
              categoryVersion.Version == articleLatestVersions.Version &&
              categoryVersion.ArticleID == articleLatestVersions.ArticleID &&
              select category).FirstOrDefault()?.Name ?? string.Empty;

KnowledgeTypeText = Regex.Replace(result, @"(\d+[\\.]?\s*)", "");
```

Comment: @Graham - no problem with edits but now first section of answer is missing important information. Shame to just remove links...

Comment: I didn't see any other explanation around it and assumed that is was complimentary information, nonessential.  As we're editing we know that the original author will be getting notified so you can come back in and improve as you see fit.

Comment: I tend to agree with @GiladGreen on this one, the edit was unnecessary and the removed link was actually critical in terms of a source for the answer.