# Find specific value from list in c# MVC

Tags: c#, linq

I have list with items like this:

```
selCountry[0] = {IdCountry = 1, LongName = "Austria", CountryUrl = "austria"}
selCountry[1] = {IdCountry = 5, LongName = "Brasil", CountryUrl = "brasil"}
```

I know `CountryUrl` and I need to find `IDcountry`

I tried these ways:

```
int idCountry;
string country = "brasil";

idCountry = Convert.ToInt32(selCountry.FirstOrDefault(m => m.CountryUrl == country).IdCountry);
idCountry = selCountry.Find(x => x.CountryUrl == country).IdCountry;
idCountry = selCountry.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CountryUrl == country).IdCountry;
```

Every time I get error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If I debug it I can see something similar like this:

> System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(...) returned null.

Where did I make a mistake?

PS: My question isn’t about, how can I manage problem with null, but, where is problem in my code, because in my example "brasil" exists in the list, so, how can I get IdCountry? If I use only only First instead FirstOrDefault I get System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching element' So how is it possible, that there is not matching element?

Declaration of my list

```
            List<CountriesListModel> selCountry = new List<CountriesListModel>();
        selCountry = listOfCoutry.CountriesList(24);
```

My model:

```
public class CountriesListModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdCountry { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LongName { get; set; }
    public string CountryUrl { get; set; }

}
```

My debug result:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3m8a81ltxn6kiew/listproblem.jpg?dl=0

Comment: `IDcountry` is not the same as `IdCountry`. How about giving us a working [mcve]?

Comment: This answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947464/selecting-a-property-from-firstordefault-in-case-firstordefault-returns-null/19947558#19947558

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selecting a property from FirstOrDefault in case FirstOrDefault returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947464/selecting-a-property-from-firstordefault-in-case-firstordefault-returns-null)

Comment: Sorry guys - IdCountry and IDcountry - its only my speling mistake. country is string - I fixed it in my example above

Comment: Still no mcve...

Comment: @JanŠalomoun: show the full declaration and initialization code of `selCountry`: it's crucial and it's missing.

Comment: Ok, one more thing: this: `selCountry[0] = {IdCountry = 1, LongName = "Austria", CountryUrl = "austria"}` does not compile, please copy past the exact code you are using. And: check if one of the items returned by `listOfCoutry.CountriesList(24);` is null.

Comment: If `selCountry[1] = {IdCountry = 5, LongName = "Brasil", CountryUrl = "brasil"}` is a return value from the `CountiesList` call (I might have missed that in my previous comment), then please copy past the data or show a screenshot, because as you said yourself: the item must be in the list. Also, check for typo's, spaces, in-consequent capitals etc.

Comment: elCountry[0] = {IdCountry = 1, LongName = "Austria", CountryUrl = "austria"} - was only example. I real case I fill it in another way and if I debug it, I can see, that list is really full of items.

Comment: @JanŠalomoun: there must be a typo then, something unexpected; to prove my claim: see https://dotnetfiddle.net/95XDgM it only says it isn't there if it isn't there ;-).

Comment: What is the value of `country` in this case? I guess it is not "brasil", but "Brasil" or "brasil " or something similar.

Comment: @Stefan - you are right.  Now I know, that there is no problem with LINQ.. Thanx - I gonna try to find, where is problem.

Comment: Now actually, in the screenshot, the list contains "brazil" with z, but in your sample above you use "brasil" with s.

Comment: @NineBerry - I'm stupid idiot! Such a stupid mistake - two hours of my life..Thanx you saved me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution:

```
selCountry.Where(w=>w.CountryUrl.Equals(country)).select(s=>s.IDcountry)
```

As you see above you need to use .select(s=>s.IDcountry) because the result of Single of Where is one item which looks like

```
{IDcountry = 1, LongName = "Austria", CountryUrl = "austria"}
```

and from that you need to select IDcountry attribute.

(You can use Single instead of Where if you are sure you will have the country always if not you need to check if we have result and it is not null then select)

Answer (score 1):

System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(...) returned null.
to fixed null value

```
 var ID = selCountry.Where(x => x.IDcountry == 1).Select(s=>s.LongName ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I thank all of you. Only problem was with -  declaration string country - brasil vs. brazil. Really thanx to @NineBery. You saved my night....